# Why Tkinter isn't filling my window vertically

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

So I'm making my first GUI app using Tkinter and My issue is that whenever I ask for my window to fill my screen, there's more or less a quarter of it that stay empty of any widgets ([like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s3fS.png)), I have no idea where this is comming from.

Here's all the relevant code:
GUI.py (main GUI code)

```
from tkinter import *

from write_env import *

BGC = '#1e1e1e'
FGC = '#ced4d4'

root = Tk()
root.title("Gamebook Maker")

# Grid setup
root.grid()
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.update()

# Frames placement
write = write_environement(root, bgc = BGC, fgc = FGC)
write.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

paragraph_list = Listbox(root, width= 20, height= 35, bg = "#333333", fg = FGC)
paragraph_list.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
paragraph_list.insert(1, "test")


root.mainloop()
```

write_env.py (code for the widgets on the right side):

```
from tkinter import *

class write_environement(Frame):
    """ class for the writing/plotting module v0.1"""

    def __init__(self, parent, bgc, fgc):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="#36393f")

        self.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight= 1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.write_tab = Text(self, bg=bgc, fg=fgc, width= 80, height= 20, font=12)
        self.write_tab.config(wrap=WORD)
        self.write_tab.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew',padx=5, pady=5)

        self.followup_list = Listbox(self, width= 120, height= 10, bg = "#333333", fg = fgc)
        self.followup_list.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew',padx=5, pady=5)
        self.followup_list.insert(1, "test")
```

edit: Atlas453's comments solved the issue, thanks

Comment: Try to remove `root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)` and also replace `root.update()` with `root.update_idletasks()`

Comment: this line `self.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')` should be deleted too, while you grid it in your main modul.

Comment: You create two rows in the root's grid, but you use only row 0.